# How to train large dataset for classification in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I have a large features dataset of around 111 Mb for classification with 217000 data points and each point has 1760000 features point. When used in training with SVM in MATLAB, it takes a lot of time.

How can be this data processed in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what sort of SVM you are building.

As a rule of thumb, with such big feature sets you need to look at linear classifiers, such as an SVM with no/the linear kernel, or logistic regression with various regularizations etc.

If you're training an SVM with a Gaussian kernel, the training algorithm has *[O(max(n,d)  min (n,d)^2)](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-computational-complexity-of-an-SVM)* complexity, where *n* is the number of examples and *d* the number of features. In your case it ends up being *O(dn^2)* which is quite big.

Comment: using linear kernel also doesn't solve the speed issue. However it at least gave the results but  still not acceptable for speed.

Comment: Well it gave you some results, so it is a little better than the other method. With almost 2 million features you (1) can't expect it to be _that_ fast and (2) can't use quadratic We can't really help you with just the small amount of details you've provided however. What does "a lot of time" mean? What's the configuration for the SVM you are using?